# Passing string to int to substring

Tags: c#

I currently get the users number like this:

```
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            rchars = numericUpDown1.Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            rchars = "3";
        }
```

string rchars; is a global variable.

So, I'm trying to remove the rchars from file names.
For example the first three characters from the file name:

```
            int num = Int32.Parse(rchars);
            foreach (FileInfo name in fpaths.GetFiles("*.mp3")
            {
                string snub = name.Name.Substring(num);
                MessageBox.Show(snub);
                System.IO.File.Move(blah + name.Name, newblah + snub);
            }
```

My question is how can I get "num" to work in a substring? Since I can't get it to be a value. Since I want to pass it from the numericUpDown. Add make "num" a value so I can remove the value from the file names.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't exaclty figure out what you mean here? If num is an int it will work as a paramter to substring. you are parsing it into an int value num, so it should work as part of the substring call...not that parsing some random number into substring without checking it doesnt exceed the length is a good idea...

Comment: The problem as exposed is not very clean to me...
It leads to several interpretation.

If you need to remove a portion of a string you should use function Remove or Replace, or just use regular expressions.

string snub = name.Name.Replace(rchars, "");

This will replaces all occourrences of rchars from the name.Name string and will put the result in sbub variable.
But I guess this is not what you are looking for, this sounds unuseful to me.

Comment: The code in the question works fine for me to remove the first n characters in the filename of all files in a folder and move it to another folder. As the NumericUpDown control can take only numeric values (it does not allow strings), I tried putting in a value of 12 without using Up or Down and it still worked. Can you please let us know if the above code is NOT working for you? Or would you like your code to do something else besides removing the first n characters?

Answer (score 2):

Value property of NumericUpDown is Decimal - that is perhaps why you are having issues. In your if block, I would consider casting the Value Property of NumericUpDown object into an integer in the true part and use integer value 3 in its else part. There after, I would avoid parsing again and give it to Substring as is.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to *remove* all occurrences of `rchars` from `name`, so why are you using `Substring`? If you want to remove the `string rchars` from `name` then just keep it as a string and use `String.Replace`:

```
string snub = name.Name.Replace( rchars, String.Empty );
```

Also, the `Value` property of a `NumericUpDown` is a `decimal`, not an `int`.

Comment: because `rchars` is a value like `"3"`, which means "remove the first 3 letters from the filename"

Comment: @Jimmy: Then what is the problem?  It should just work.  You should simply declare `rchars` as an `int` as that's what `String.Substring` expects.  There is no reason to coerce this thing to a string and then back again. Also, there is (technically) no such thing as a global variable in C#.

Comment: well, I actually don't understand the question either, but OP does say 'for example, [remove] the first three characters from a filename', so I don't really see it as intending to be a replacement.

Comment: @Jimmy: Yeah, I caught that after you commented.  I actually thought you were the OP, oops...

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to replace the value "3" within the name of a file with something else/remove it? Like this:

original file:

```
string fiename = "myfile3.mp3";
```

remove/replace selected number (in this case 3):

```
string num = "3";
filename.replace(num, "");
```

should end up with a filename "myfile.mp3"